# Spring cloud stream: Bean 'input' defined in 'Sink' already exists in 'Processor'

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Processor is the interface extending Sink and Source. 
Sink creates a channel with name 'input'

In my application I have:
1. a class with `@EnableBinding(Source.class)` which creates 'output' channel. 
2. A class with `@EnableBinding(Processor.class)` which has a method annotated with  `@Transformer(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = "myOutputChannel")`
3. A class with '@EnableBinding(Sink.class)' which has a method annotated with `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myOutputChannel")`

Apparently I am not binding "input" twice, but when I run the application I get this error:

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'input' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Sink: bean definition with this name already exists - org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Processor;
```

any ideas why this might be? what I am doing wrong?

I had an application dropped on me which had three component applications Source, Sink, and Processor. The source class was tied to `@EnableBinding(Source.class)`, The sink class tied to `@EnableBinding(Sink.class)`, and the processor class was tied to `@EnableBinding(Processor.class)`. When I updated the application to use new spring boot and cloud dependencies (spring boot 2.1.5 and cloud version is Greenwich.SR1) I started to see this error above. I updated Sink.class and Source.class to Processor.class to make sure that `input` and `output` beans are created once only and that made it work.

Comment: That is a correct behavior and the exception explains you the issue. What is your question? I mean what are you trying to accomplish by creating multiple channels with the same name?

Comment: "multiple channels with same name" - -  where I am doing it?

Comment: You have 3 classes (based on your explanation) annotated with EnableBinding that have the same values,.

Comment: you mean for EnableBinding I can use Processor.class only, as it is inheriting Source and Sink so those channel beans will be available anyway. so I can use @EnableBiniding(Processor.class) everywhere right?

Comment: I am still not sure what is your question or what are you trying to accomplish. But just like with any Spring bean, you can not have two beans with the same name. Perhaps if you can explain your use and what made you configure EnableBinding three times?

Comment: added paragraph to my question. I got it working but not sure if thats the right way.

Comment: This might help you clarify the confusion: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#_programming_model